# In Java, where in the package/source hierarchy should resources be placed?

Tags: java, resources, package

Say I have developed a game, and placed it in the package structure:

```
com.dxmio.games.breakout
```

Where then is the 'best practice' place to put resources like audio and images that the game uses?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have seen this handled in a number of different ways:

- Place your resources directly in a subdirectory under `com/dmxio/games/breakout` (e.g. `/com/dmxio/games/breakout/images/foo.gif` and `/com/dmxio/games/breakout/images/bar.gif`)
- Place your resources in a jar along with your class files (e.g. `foo.gif` and `bar.gif` bundled in `breakout.jar`)
- Place your resources in a separate 'resources jar' in a subdirectory under `com/dmxio/games/breakout` (e.g. `foo.gif` and `bar.gif` bundled in `/com/dmxio/games/breakout/images/images.jar`)

I tend to favor the last option.

You can then use the [`java.lang.Class.getResource()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) method to retrieve your resources.

Answer (score 17):

You can always adopt a standard Maven approach to your project and put all application source files in:

```
{home}/src/main/java/com/dmxio/games/breakout
```

and then your resources live in:

```
{home}/src/main/resources/com/dmxio/games/breakout
```

and your tests then live in:

```
{home}/src/test/java/com/dmxio/games/breakout
```

This structure is a standard convention to structuring projects in the Maven world.  It brings a lot of advantages with it, which you may want to look at.  You can check out the resources section here: [Apache Maven Guides - How do I add resources to my JAR](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR)

Alternatively :) the other answer's approach here is just fine...

Comment: +1 I favor using this convention. And it simplifies things if someday you want to build the project with maven.

Comment: Definitely +1 for sticking to Maven convention. It's a decent standard structure, will help if you ever use Maven, plus other developers will immediately know how to navigate around this as well.